# How to insert images per cell in libre calc based on an entry in another column

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet were in one column the file names of jpgs are. I would like to analyse the images and code them (e.g. tree in image yes or no) in another column. Therefore i would like to automatically insert all images in another column, reasonable resized, based on the file name entry.

Is there a way in Libe Calc how to do this?
Like:

```
=IMAGE('some/path/to/image/folder' + A1)
```

Were in column A the image names are.

Comment: This is not an actual programming question, until you find that you need a macro to do this. Provide some code with your effort, and we will have a look. (Hint: I'm quite sure that you will need a macro.)

Answer (score 0):

The macro you need has already been written and is ready to use - see [**Links to images**](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/links-to-images)